# java Date problems

Tags: java, date

Hello everybody why the output of this is 0 instead of 9 ? thanks

```
Date dateNaiss=null;
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
try {
    dateNaiss = sdf.parse("1992-10-10");
} catch (ParseException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("the mounth of this date is : "+dateNaiss.getMonth());
```

Comment: What does `mm` represent?

Comment: In addition to the answers, note, that Date.getMonth() is deprecated, you should use, Calendar class

Comment: In Java 8+, `LocalDate.parse( "1992-10-10" )`

Answer (score 4):

Because `mm` is minutes (not month). I believe you wanted

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
```

with

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

`mm` is for minutes and `MM` is for months

Also, you shouldn't be using `getMonth()`, it has been deprecated. Use `Calendar` class and get `Calendar.MONTH` from it instead.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this chart from the documentation:

[image]

Notice that `m` is used for the minute, and `M` is used for the month.